# how to sniff packets, modify and then send

Tags: python, scapy, sniffing

I want to sniff IP packets and then change ToS field to `1` and add options to IP header then send modified packet instead of original packet.
I found that can do this with scapy but it seems not working.
can anyone help me with this?

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.inet import IP

def chgSend(x):
    x[IP].tos = 1
    send(x)
while 1:
    sniff(filter="ip src host 10.0.0.2", prn=chgSend)
```

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: Does changing `send(x)` to `sendp(x)` help?

Comment: @BrianBienvenu I used `sendp(x)` then it started to send lots of packets after first packet captured!

Comment: Sounds better. You have a `while 1:`, so it's going to continually capture packets and then resend them. I think It's likely that your sniff is seeing the packets generated by Scapy's `sendp()` - it's effectively feeding itself. You'll need to add some extra logic in your code to stop that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I'm able to spoof IP address and change ToS field with this code:

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.inet import IP


def change_send(pckt):
    actual_src = pckt[IP].src
    pckt[IP].src = "192.168.1.5"
    pckt[IP].tos = 1
    sendp(pckt)
    print("We changed source from " + actual_src + " to " + pckt[IP].src)


while 1:
    sniff(filter="ip src host 192.168.1.2", prn=change_send)
```

If you don't want to change source IP address, be sure that you wont stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: You also have to set every checksum to `None` so that they are correctly re-calculated while being sent